# How to Git merge a branch that only contains a subfolder of trunk?

Tags: git, merge, git-svn

I am currently working on a project using svn (server is version 1.4 which means no modern merge tools available).

I want to merge a branch with quite a few weeks of work in it. The problem is that back when the branch was created, it was made as a copy only of a subfolder.

Svn structure of project:

```
/trunk/folder1
              /file1
              /file2
       folder2
       folder3
       ...
```

Now I'm struggling to merge a branch back into trunk.

Now the problem is that the guy that created the branch only copied /trunk/folder1 and not the entire trunk. This creates a problem for git-svn, as it thinks that I created a bunch of files in the folder.

```
 git co master
 git merge branch1
 ...
 create mode 100644 trunk/file1
 create mode 100644 trunk/file2
```

(assuming that the files were originally in `/trunk/folder1/file1`)

The original reason i'm not using svn for this, is because of too many conflickts. (`svn merge` requires server 1.5+ and we're only on 1.4, `svnmerge.py` can only merge small chunks at a time and requires a LOT of mental overload ... i have used a half day to get only half way through)

Using `git merge` seems promising, but at first I need to tell git to use a subfolder of my master branch as merge target. How is that done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `subtree` merge strategy was created specifically for this use case. It looks for files in the remote branch that match files in a subdirectory in the local branch, and if it does find them, it rewrites all the paths to make the two directory structures match up, before invoking the "normal" `recursive` merge strategy.

So, try

```
git merge -s subtree branch1
```

Comment: Thanks, but trying this command directly on master branch just creates files (as I described in my question). How do I tell git which directory to use?

Comment: This seems to work (when applied from master's /folder1). I'm still missing to dcommit back to svn, but the git merge runs really, really fast

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use **subtree** merge strategy.

For ***first merge***, take a look at the following references:

- [Subtree merging and you](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/subtree-merging-and-you/) by Markus Prinz
- [How to use the subtree merge strategy](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) in Git documentation (should be present as `howto/using-merge-subtree.html` in Git docs, in `/usr/share/doc/git-<version>` on Linux).

Or use **[git-subtree](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree)** tool by Avery Pennarun, mentioned on [InterfacesFrontendsAndTools](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#git-subtree) page on Git wiki.

For ***subsequent merges*** it should be enough to specify subtree merge strategy:

```
$ git pull -s subtree <remote>
```

or

```
$ git merge -s subtree <branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off solution, I'd take that annoying "subfolder branch" in my local git repo's working copy, branch off a temporary working branch ("tmp-subdir") for safety, and then use `git filter-branch` on that working branch to move all its files into the proper place.

As that is probably lacking the rest of "trunk"'s files, I'd then branch off trunk ("tmp-trunk"), and replay/cherry-pick all the changesets from "tmp-subdir" onto "tmp-trunk".

Then it should be possible to merge that with "trunk".

This should work, but probably someone will come up with a one-liner to achieve the same thing. :-)

Comment: Interesting strategy. But a key issue is how to use `git filter-branch` to move all files into a subdirectory

Comment: With the `--tree-filter` option and some shell script magic. But you'll certainly be better off using [Jörg's `git merge -s subtree` one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783876/how-to-git-merge-a-branch-that-only-contains-a-subfolder-of-trunk/1785690#1785690).